# Addition and multiplication in terms of arrows in the poset category where an existing arrow means "divides".

Tags: elementary-number-theory, category-theory, integers

Let $C$ be the category where objects are **non-negative integers** and $m \to n$ in $C$ exists (and uniquely) iff $m \mid n$.  It is a poset category, and $0$ is terminal with $1$ initial.  The $\gcd$, $(m,n)$, is a categorical product of $m,n$.

Then addition $m+n$ has the property that it is the (hopefully unique, but it's not, see below) object $a$ existing for any two objects $m,n$ such that if $d$ is not the initial object and $d \to $ any two of $\{m,n,a\}$ then automatically $d \to m, d \to n, d\to a$ all exist.

[image: mn pullback square and m+n diagram]

Multiplication has the property that the above square is a pushout if and only if $(m,n) = 1$.

Can you think of any more interesting categorical constructions in $C$? Also, what construction would define $mn$?  I don't think it's another product. Can you think of any basic property that we know is a theorem in classical mathematics, yet has a  nice proof using the above constructions?

**Partial proof of claim about $+$.**  Clearly $m + n$ exists for all non-negative integers $m,n$ and if, without loss of generality, $d \mid (m+n), m$, then $dk = (m+n), dk' = m$ so $dk = dk' + n$ and $d(k-k') = n$ and therefore $d \mid n$.  And if $d \mid m, d\mid n$ then clearly $d \mid (m+n)$. And we're done showing existence of such an object.  Then... ?

---

Okay, according to a comment.  The construciton isn't unique.  So my question is what additional constraints to the $+$ construction will cause it to be unique and equal to $+$ on integers?

Comment: Doesn't $\max\{m-n,n-m\}$ also have that property?

Comment: @NoahSchweber then my question is how do we characterise further to scope in addition and only addition?

Comment: You should probably modify the question accordingly then.

Comment: @NoahSchweber okay, added to question

Comment: In fact, note that any three distinct primes stand in that relation to each other: if $p_1,p_2$ are distinct primes then the only thing dividing them both is $1$, which divides everything else. So if $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ is a set of three distinct primes, then anything with a morphism to two of them has a morphism to the third.

Comment: @NoahSchweber added "if $d$ is not the initial object".

Comment: OK, multiply everything involved by a fourth prime: if $p_1,p_2,p_3,q$ are distinct primes, then anything with a morphism to two of $\{p_1q,p_2q,p_3q\}$ has a morphism to the third (the only options are $q$ and $1$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber note that excluding initial object is not a special thing done only here, I've seen it done in other areas of category theory.  You'd have to of course because there automatically exists and arrow from $1 \to a$ where $a$ now is any object.

Comment: @NoahSchweber okay, that's a good point, now will work on that :)

Comment: Addition cannot be defined using just the category structure, since there are automorphisms of the category that do not preserve addition (permute the primes).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no hope of recovering addition as a categorical construction in this poset, because addition isn't preserved under automorphisms of this poset. Write $\nu_p(n)$ for the largest exponent of a prime $p$ dividing $n$. We have

$$m \mid n \Leftrightarrow \nu_p(m) \le \nu_p(n)$$

which means that, as a poset, the divisibility poset is a (restricted) product of chains, one for each prime. In particular it has automorphisms given by permutations acting on the primes (which switch around the exponents in prime factorizations), and addition is totally scrambled by any such automorphism. But automorphisms preserve products, coproducts, and any other purely categorical constructions.

This objection doesn't apply to multiplication so one might hope for a categorical  construction that produces multiplication but I am not seeing it. The problem basically reduces to the problem for a single chain: that is, in a chain $0 \le 1 \le 2 \le 3 \dots $ can you recover addition using only categorical constructions? I don't see a way to do this.

The most interesting thing people do with this poset that I know of is to prove [Mobius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula), which has a generalization to posets.

Comment: How do you define "purely categorical construction?"  What if there is a new construction that no one has considered before?

Comment: The question of defining multiplication reminds me of this old MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69037/categorical-definition-of-the-ideal-product-within-the-category-of-rings

Comment: @AlgebraicGeometryStudent: whatever a purely categorical construction is, it should be preserved by automorphisms. If it isn't preserved by automorphisms it definitely does not deserve the name "purely categorical." Similarly a "purely group-theoretic" construction should be preserved by automorphisms of groups, etc.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan that makes sense.  Thank you! Any idea what category I should be in if I want to "stare directly at integers" in which say $+$ has a categorical construction and is not something like a groupoid where every arrow adds or subtracts an integer.  Something more novel than that.

Comment: Or, more directly relevant to this example where we're looking at ideals in just a single ring, [this old MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14739/how-can-i-define-the-product-of-two-ideals-categorically) that you asked :)

Comment: @AlgebraicGeometryStudent: the standard categorification of addition is the coproduct in $\text{FinSet}$ or $\text{Set}$ depending on taste. It's tricky to directly categorify addition on integers because products and coproducts never have nontrivial inverses (this is a nice exercise).

Comment: @Eric: yes, that was a revelation for me at the time! I learned how to rule out categorical constructions early :)

Comment: @AlgebraicGeometryStudent: $\text{FinSet}$ and $\text{Set}$ together with product, coproduct, and exponentials are really very good categorifications of ordinary arithmetic. You get commutativity, associativity, distributivity, and all of the usual exponent laws out of universal properties alone. The term you want to look up is "cartesian closed category" to learn more about this.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan inverses would be gotten by generalizing Grothendieck group of $\Bbb{N}$ to categories, maybe?

Comment: @AlgebraicGeometryStudent: yes, that's a thing you can do.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan what's that construction called or is there a link?

Comment: It's just called the Grothendieck group, as far as I know. The standard application of this construction is to producing K-theory from the Grothendieck group of the category of vector bundles, although there it's typical to do a slightly different thing where you quotient by relations coming from short exact sequences.

Comment: $m+\cdot : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ could be described as the unique equivalence from $\mathbb{N}$ to the coslice category $m \backslash \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 7):

There's very little you can do in this poset. (I'm going to eschew the language of category theory, and just talk in terms of posets, since I think that makes things much clearer.)

Automorphisms of this poset are basically the same as permutations of the primes. Consequently, anything not invariant under permuting primes is not definable in any sense in that poset. So we can easily show for example that addition isn't definable: the automorphism $\alpha$ generated by the permutation of primes swapping $5$ and $7$ and leaving all other primes fixed does not respect addition (we have $2+3=5$ but $\alpha(2)+\alpha(3)\not=\alpha(5)$).

(A relevant topic you may be interested in is [**Skolem arithmetic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_arithmetic); this is the first-order theory of the natural numbers with multiplication. This is actually more expressive than the first-order theory of the poset in question, but if we go a bit beyond first-order logic the two structures are appropriately equivalent.)